# Преобразование матрицы в Python

Tags: python, матрицы

Имеется матрица вида:

```
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
                  0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
                  0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
                  0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
                  0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Необходимо создать массив данных несущих в себе информацию о значениях отличных от 0 и их координатах в исходном массиве.
Примерно [ x, y, 1] и т.д.

```
    import pandas as pd
    def row(s):
      return s[0] != '0'

    file = 'samp.xlsx'
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    print(xl.sheet_names)
    df1 = xl.parse('Лист1')
    print (df1)
    df2 = filter(row, df1)   
    print (df2)
```

В меру понимания пробовал фильтрацию, но не выводится матрица df2

Comment: Ваш код где? Нам не надо задания давать. И что это за матрица такая? Это список списков?

Comment: Делаете цикл в цикле - по `y` и по `x`, да обходите матрицу. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Без numpy

Перебираем строки, в строках перебираем элементы. Если элемент не нулевой выдаём адрес и значение. На верхнем уровне собираем всё в список:

```
def nonzeros(a):
    for i, r in enumerate(a):
        for j, v in enumerate(r):
            if v != 0:
                yield i, j, v


a = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
b = list(nonzeros(a))
print(b)
```

> ```
> $ python convert.py
> [(1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1),
> (2, 4, 1), (2, 5, 1), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1), (3, 3, 1), (3, 4, 1),
> (3, 5, 1), (4, 2, 1), (4, 3, 1), (4, 4, 1)]
> ```

### С numpy

`b = np.nonzero(a)` возвращает списки ненулевых координат: отдельно список индексов строк, отдельно список индексов столбцов.

`c = a[b]` возвращает все значения адресованные `b`.

`b + (c, )` собирает индексы и значения вместе.

`np.column_stack` превращает список массивов в единый двумерный массив. Это аналог `zip`.

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
])

# b = (
#     array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]),
#     array([2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4])
# )
b = np.nonzero(a)

# c = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
c = a[b]

# d = [[1 2 1] [1 3 1] ... [4 4 1]]
# or use d = list(zip(*b, c))
d = np.column_stack(b + (c, ))
print(d)
```

> ```
> $ python convert.py
> [[1 2 1]
>  [1 3 1]
>  [1 4 1]
>  [2 1 1]
>  [2 2 1]
>  [2 3 1]
>  [2 4 1]
>  [2 5 1]
>  [3 1 1]
>  [3 2 1]
>  [3 3 1]
>  [3 4 1]
>  [3 5 1]
>  [4 2 1]
>  [4 3 1]
>  [4 4 1]]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Самый просто способ:

```
matrix =   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

arr = []

for x in range(len(matrix)):
    for y in range(len(matrix[x])):
        if matrix[x][y] != 0:
            arr.append([x, y, matrix[x][y]])

for i in arr:
    print(' '.join(list(map(str, i))))
```

Если обязателен `numpy`, то я тут не помощник...

Answer (score 0):

Ну, вероятно, можно так:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

arr = np.array(a)
coords = np.argwhere(arr!=0)

res = list(zip(coords[:,0], coords[:,1], arr[coords[:,0], coords[:,1]]))
```

res:

```
[(1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1), (2, 4, 1), (2, 5, 1), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1), (3, 3, 1), (3, 4, 1), (3, 5, 1), (4, 2, 1), (4, 3, 1), (4, 4, 1)]
```